# Accessing library objects after their initialization without using excessive number of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine a standard scenario where I have multiple native-HTML elements, say, `select`s, and I use some external library to finetune them, say, [select2.js](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).
To apply library to the native elements, I do the following:

HTML:

```
<select id = 'foo1'></select>
<select id = 'foo2'></select>
<select id = 'foo3'></select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').select2({/* options */});
```

Now, imagine there's some library method, let's call it `select2_method`, that I want to apply to one of my `select`s. Clearly, I need the select2 object to apply it. But the problem is that I just applied select2 constructor to my select elements without saving the objects that it returned !

This problem would not arise if I called the constructor of external library separately for each HTML element, and assign the value of the constructor to some variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $foo1_select2 = $('#foo1').select2({/* options */});
        var $foo2_select2 = $('#foo2').select2({/* options */});
        var $foo3_select2 = $('#foo3').select2({/* options */});
        // ...
        $foo1_select2.select2_method(/*...*/) // applying the desired library method
```

The obvious pitfall with approach is that I would have to

- increase number of variables (one select2 object for one HTML select element)
- increase code size and apply select2 to each element instead of looping through all target elements and applying the library in one shot
- possibly use global vars

What is the common approach in such cases ? Do you have to save objects in a loop and then somehow get access to the object by initial native-HTML element ?
I mean, something like

```
var select2_array = []; 
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').each(function(){
              select2_array.push($(this).select2({/* options */});)
```

But then what would be method to map `select2_array` elements and native-HTML `select`s identified by their HTML ids?

I hope, I clearly stated the question. In fact, this problem makes my project development really slow, and I would highly appreciate sharing best-practice regarding JS tools to organize code in this respect

Comment: what about grouping the selectors in one `var $foo1_select2 = $('#foo1, #foo2, #foo3').select2({/* options */});`

Comment: Well, what if you want to apply library method to foo1, foo2 only without foo3 ?